# WSDL File for PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to make a request to the FedEx Tracking API. In their implementation, they make use of PHP's SoapClient object. When creating the object they supply a url which is supposed to be a path to a WSDL file. I have not worked with SOAP, XML, or WSDL in the past so this is all fairly new to me. I have read several articles on these topics but am still having issues.

For the WSDL file that they supple SoapClient

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);
```

Where/how would one find/create the necessary WSDL file? Is this something I would create or would FedEx have a file I would need to download?

Detailed information is appreciated.

Comment: That URL must be shown in the API documentation, it isn't something you can guess. Unfortunately, developer documentation in large companies often seems to be written by the marketing team.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer this for anyone who has similar issues in the future locating a WSDL file from FedEx. Navigate to [this location](https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/web-services/process.html#documentation) and then click on what is circled in the image below. This will download additional documents (not included with the documentation download) which will include a WSDL file for the selected service.

[image]

The WSDL file is (simply put) a description of how the service we are interacting with works. Therefore, FedEx would be the only party to have this information.

[image]